# Javascript json_encode > JSON.parse() array

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I the following PHP code:

```
echo "<img src='../images/edit.png' onclick='showEditDiv(" . json_encode($row) . ");'>";
```

Here is the HTML result:

```
<img src='../images/edit.png' onclick='showEditDiv({"ID":"2","NAME":"John Smith","EMAIL":"johnsmith@domain.com"});'>
```

And here is the Javascript code:

```
function showEditDiv(data) {
  alert(data);
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  alert(data);
  for (i=0; i< data.length; i++){ 
    alert(data[i]);
  };
}
```

The problem is I'm not getting the desired array in the JS parameter.
The first alert shows "[object Object]" and that's all, no more alerts.
Where is the problem? My code is based on the examples I found here. All I want is to pass an array to JS function, which is in a separated .js file. I don't want to use JQuery, prefer native JS.

Comment: What you have is not an array. It is an object literal. What exactly do you want

Comment: @PSL: I believe OP is using "array" in PHP sense (hash-array-bag-thingy).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You aren't passing JSON to the function (JSON would be a string, hence ending/beginning with quotes). What you're passing is a JavaScript object literal. See the difference:

#### Object literal

```
{"ID":"2","NAME":"John Smith","EMAIL":"johnsmith@domain.com"}
```

#### JSON string

```
"{\"ID\":\"2\",\"NAME\":\"John Smith\",\"EMAIL\":\"johnsmith@domain.com\"}\"
// or, easier than escaping all those quotes..
'{"ID":"2","NAME":"John Smith","EMAIL":"johnsmith@domain.com"}'
```

Of course, for your purposes, the object literal may be easier to work with. In that case you just need to remove the `JSON.parse` from your JavaScript code:

```
function showEditDiv(data) {
    // The below won't work unless you change your input data to a
    // JS array literal..
    /* for (i=0; i< data.length; i++){ 
        alert(data[i]);
    }; */

    // ..but you can do this (though it's risky to iterate through keys
    // on an object without at least using HasOwnProperty)
    for (var key in data) {
        alert(data[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a JSON string? You mean an escaped string here. Or do you call `&lt;span&gt;` an html string?

Comment: @Neikos: JSON is always a string. JS object is almost the same thing, but as a structure in JavaScript. `{}` is (an empty) JavaScript object; `"{}"` is JSON data format corresponding to it.

Comment: No. `{ "data": "value" }` is both JSON and JS.

Comment: @Neikos Context is obviously important and you're arguing pointless semantics here. What you just posted is JSON, but it's not JSON within JavaScript code because it isn't a string.

Comment: Furthermore, JSON is *always* a string because JSON is defined in terms of Unicode encoding. What you posted isn't JSON if you paste it into a JavaScript script, it is *only* an object literal.

Comment: You do know that your onclick attribute ends with the second `'` (before the json_encoded data). How OP had it was fine and better, just have to remove the `JSON.parse` line.

Comment: @Musa Whoops, you're right. Didn't look close enough. I agree that not passing it as a string is better but I figured this is what the OP would want to see.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. I modified my code, but still not getting that bloody array :)

Comment: @ChrisHayes You trying to fix the attribute with a js escape but the attribute is html so you have to use an html escaping method.

Comment: @Musa Oh, right. God, I don't miss working in PHP one bit. I'm just going to replace it with the object literal form so I can still be sane when this question is done.

Comment: Thank you! I think my question and/or sample code didn't clarify what I was looking for, luckily you just find out what I needed :)

Answer (score 5):

> All I want is to pass an array to JS function

That's an object in JS, not an array. (PHP nomenclature is a bit weird.) And you have successfully passed it. However, when you convert an object into a string (which is what `alert` has to do), it shows up as `[object Object]`. If you want the string representation, convert it back into a string:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

You don't need to `JSON.parse` it, since it already is an object - you have inserted it as a literal from PHP, not as a string. In fact, running `JSON.parse` in your code should cause an error, which is why no more alerts - code stops, complaining about bad taste in `JSON.parse`'s mouth.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a subset of Javascript. Which means that if used appropriately it is valid javascript as well.

In this case you are effectively putting through an object, which is also what your alert has told you. The JSON.parse should then error.

If you want to pass an array you have to change your data source. (Although from the looks of it, an array is not required.)

Answer (score 0):

```
{"ID":"2","NAME":"John Smith","EMAIL":"johnsmith@domain.com"} is already a json.
```

That's why your `alert` is `[object Object]`. Also It's not an array for loop. You can get it's data by this way:

```
function showEditDiv(data) {
  alert(data);
  alert(data.ID);
  alert(data.NAME); // etc..
}
```

If you want an array, here's the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/LjS3P/).

Comment: Thanks, this is a useful info! The only problem I want an array, not an object.

Comment: So what do you want when use "alert(data[i]);"? The ID with value equa 2? Or the whole object with all of info above?

Comment: Well that is a good question :) I'm not familiar with JS, I need a same associative array than I have in the PHP, therefore as you pointed out, my code is completely wrong.